# How to use monolog in many php classes

Tags: wordpress, monolog

I have written a Wordpress plugin which has many PHP classes.  My plugin also implements monolog to send log messages (to Slack in this case).

What is the best way to access monolog inside my classes?  Currently I pass down the same instance of `Monolog\Logger` to the constructor of every class that needs it.  There must be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern:

https://gist.github.com/laverboy/fd0a32e9e4e9fbbf9584

Comment: My ideas were to use traits, interfaces or inheritance.  With the singleton I wouldn't have to write any additional lines of code into my classes or class declarations.  I could edit each line from `$this->logger->info( ... )` to `Log::info( ... )`.

Comment: Is this not desired?

Comment: Yes it is, of course, I was just expanding on your answer for brevity.  I had hoped for a few more comments as, on the face of it Wordpress and Monolog should be two popular topics.  Very happy to accept your answer however and I am implementing it now in my project.